# No need to run 'GRANT postgres_exporter TO <MASTER_USER>' on aws RDS PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, prometheus

Per [postgresql_exporter doc](https://github.com/prometheus-community/postgres_exporter#running-as-non-superuser). In order to create one new user `postgres_exporter`  for Prometheus PostgreSQL exporter. Here are the sample codes

> ```sql
> ALTER USER postgres_exporter WITH PASSWORD 'password';
> ALTER USER postgres_exporter SET SEARCH_PATH TO postgres_exporter,pg_catalog;
> -- If deploying as non-superuser (for example in AWS RDS), uncomment the GRANT
> -- line below and replace <MASTER_USER> with your root user.
> -- GRANT postgres_exporter TO <MASTER_USER>;
> GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE postgres TO postgres_exporter;
> ```

One special SQL is `GRANT postgres_exporter TO <MASTER_USER>`. I am confused about it. I just remove it and run with the following codes to create one new user `postgres_exporter`

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION __tmp_create_user() returns void as $$
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT
          FROM   pg_catalog.pg_user
          WHERE  usename = 'postgres_exporter') THEN
    CREATE USER postgres_exporter;
  END IF;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;

SELECT __tmp_create_user();
DROP FUNCTION __tmp_create_user();

ALTER USER postgres_exporter WITH PASSWORD 'password';
ALTER USER postgres_exporter SET SEARCH_PATH TO pg_catalog;

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE postgres TO postgres_exporter;

GRANT pg_monitor to postgres_exporter;
```

And this new user works well in PostgreSQL exporter with PostgreSQL version 10.

Shall we think this operation `GRANT postgres_exporter1 TO <MASTER_USER>` is useless? Please correct us if something is wrong or anything missing?